# How do we tell if an O.D.E is First-Order homogenous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

According to the definition given to me, a first order homogeneous ODE is of this form:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(\frac{y}{x})$

So, my understanding is that, if it's a function of x and y, it's first order homogenous.

So why is $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-y^2-e^{(x-y)}}{2xy+e^{(x+y)}}$$ not a first order homogenous?

How can we tell if it's first order homogenous, or if it's a more general exact equation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Homogenous usually means that the ODE can be written in the form
$$F(y',y) = 0$$
(independent on $x$)...

Comment: Another way to check that an ODE is n-th order homogeneous: given in the form $\frac{dx}{dy}=f(x,y)$, $f$ should satisfy that $f(\lambda x,\lambda y)=\lambda^n f(x,y)$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, which is not the case for any $n$ here.

Comment: @AlexR That's true for linear ODEs. For general ODEs, the equation is homogeneous if there exists some $\alpha$ that for every $\lambda$, you have $f(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \lambda^{\alpha}f(x,y)$

Comment: @5xum Thanks for telling me, I'm not that much into ODEs :)